# How to make Chrome play video in new tab instead of downloading?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, tabs

Code example:

```
<a href="https://example.com/video.mp4" target="_blank">This downloads the video</a>

<a href="video.mp4" target="_blank">This plays the video in a new tab</a>
```

Firefox plays both those links in a new tab. Chrome however does not and behaves as the anchor texts suggest. How can I make Chrome play the first one in a new tab?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `<video>` tag

```
<video width="350" height="250" controls>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This will embed your video in the current page.  However, you will be able to control how your video is displayed.  I'm actually not exactly sure how to make chrome open the video in a new tab without adding a new plugin to chrome.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else stumbling across this problem. For me the problem was due to no Content-Type header being provided in the request that downloaded the video. Adding a Content-Type header of "video/mp4" fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to embed the video instead of htperlinking it. The behavior of how browsers handle hyperlinks depends completely on the browser